# Поместить все данные при парсинге в массив

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Есть набор ссылок, с которых парсится название фирмы, и название конкретной специальности. Далее эти два значения, нужно занести в массив и так как ссылок N количество то и данных должно быть несколько. Парсит он все, но каждый раз он как я понял данные заносит заново и каждый раз просто меняет значение. Подскажите как поместить все данные в 1 массив?

```
def search(url):
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get(url)
    html_doc = driver.page_source
    tempnew = 'empty'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")
    temp = soup.find(attrs={"data-qa":"vacancy-serp__vacancy-title"}, string="IT-специалист")
    if temp == None:
        temp = tempnew
    else:
        temp = soup.find(attrs={"data-qa":"vacancy-serp__vacancy-title"}, string="IT-специалист").get_text() 
    temp2 = soup.find(attrs={"data-qa":"company-header-title-name"})
    a = []
    a.append(temp)
    a.append(temp2.text)
    print(a)
```

Comment: Наверное, надо убрать a = [] из функции, чтобы список рос при каждом вызове функции

Comment: @СергейКох все помогло спасибо, теперь нормально заполняет!